# two pendulums, which pendulum has shorter period

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A pendulum clock problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5587/a-pendulum-clock-problem)

There are two pendulums.

First pendulum consists of a rod of length L and flat heavy disk of radius R (R < L), disk is connected rigidly to the rod such that the plane of the disk is vertical. Mass of the rod is negligible compared to mass of the disk. Center of the disk is at distance L from the upper point of the rod.

Second pendulum has same rod of length L and same disk, but the disk is not connected rigidly to the rod. Disk can rotate freely around its center at which it is attached to the rod at distance L from the upper end of the rod. Disk remains in vertical plane, as if there is ball bearing atached to the rod.

Which pendulum has smaller period at small deviations, if their periods are different.

Comment: Indeed, but the answer in the duplicate question is in my opinion too complex.  No offense.

Comment: I think that the link posted by Mark is an exact duplicate of this, and the answer there is quite clean.

Comment: Well, never mind, I guess I don't fit into the club.  It was still fun  answering the questions, and very instructive for myself too.  Even seemingly stupid questions force you to reassess your own knowledge or improve lectures.  Greets!

Comment: @Pygmalion Don't confuse simple and short.

Comment: @Pygmalion that's a perfect opportunity to post your own, less complex answer to the other question. If others agree with your opinion, there should be plenty of upvotes to be had.

Comment: First of all, I wasn't aware of the other question; it was not my intention to upheld duplicates.  Secondly, I do not think the original question will get any further attention, so answering there is futile.  And finally, I agree that simpleness is matter of taste, and I might be influenced by the logic of students of civil engineering in my classroom.  I would lose all of them after the second line of the longer explanation, while, hopefully, a quarter would understood the shorter explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the first pendulum, disk has to rotate and this is classical **physical pendulum**.  In the case of the second pendulum, you don't expect disk to rotate (the only force is in the center of mass, so there is no torque), so therefore you simply have only transitional movement - **mathematical pendulum**.

Using equation for periods of physical pendulum

$$T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{I}{m g l}}$$

and noting, that

$$I = I_\textrm{cm} + m l^2,$$

where $I_\textrm{cm} > 0$ is center-of-mass inertia of the disk, you get

$$T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g} + \frac{I_\text{cm}}{m g l}}.$$

On the other hand equation for periods of mathematical pendulum

$$T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}.$$

Obviously, period is smaller for the second pendulum.