# Moment of inertia of a system in different cases

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

> A rod of mass $m$ and length $l$ is pivoted at one end to ceiling and free to rotate in the vertical plane. A disc of radius $R$, which is less than $l$, can be fixed at its other end in 2 ways:
>
> 1. The disc is free to rotate about its centre.
> 2. The disc cannot rotate about its centre.
>
> Compare the moment of inertia of the two systems about the pivoted end.

I have been thinking for several hours and can't think why they would be different. There is no torque on the disc (about centre) and hence there should be no difference between the two cases.

I found a similar question here but that uses a Lagrangian approach, which I have not studied (I'm in XII standard). Please explain why the moment of inertia will be different in the two cases.

Comment: A diagram would be helpful to understand what is being asked.

Comment: @kleingordon I have added the diag. i just made in paint...seems fine?

Comment: The period of a pendulum is inversely proportional to the square root of its length, so the inside edge of the disk has a slightly shorter period than the outside edge.

Comment: @JohnRennie This is not a simple pendulum.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5587/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I told that I don't know Langragian mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the system in equilibrium, with the rod hanging straight down. Imagine taking a marker and drawing a vertical diameter across the disk.

If the rod were fixed to the disk's center so that the disk could not rotate, then would this marker line still be vertical mid swing? What does this tell you about the rotation of the disk around its central axis relative to its starting position?

If the disk were not rigidly attached as in the former case, would there now be any torque on the disk around its central axis? What would the marker line look like mid swing in this case?

Comment: the line would be in line with rod when disc is fixed... Intuition tells me that line would be vertical every time in second case...But I don't see any torque acting on disc about central axis...

Comment: Yes. So in the first case, the disk has rotated around its central axis, in addition to rotating around the pivot point of the rod. The rod itself has to provide the torque. Think of the second case again. The disk doesn't want to rotate around its central axis if it doesn't have to, so it just slides around its connection to the rod. But if it can't slide like that, then the connection with the rod has to do some extra work.

Comment: Ok... I get most of it...so the first case has got more inertia? Please explain quantitavely.

Comment: I'm guessing this is homework, so I can't solve the problem completely for you. Think some more about how much rotation occurs in the two cases, and I'm sure the answer will come to you.

Comment: This is not homework....I was just doing problems from my book and there was a problem which demanded their time periods and after searching a lot on the internet I found that their inertia will be different (T= 2 pi sqrt(I/mgl))  So I asked about it here...PLease help...

Comment: Ok. The difference in moments of inertia of the system comes down to the moment of inertia of the disk about its center of mass, $1/2 \, M_{\rm disk} R^2$. In the second case the disk doesn't rotate about its central axis, so that contribution to the moment of inertia of the entire system is zero. In the first case, you need to include that contribution. In both cases, you still must account for the rotation of the disk about the pivot point of the rod. See page 10 of this document: http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/chapter24.pdf

Comment: I get it now... But here it is mentioned that the disc does not rotate about its centre ?

Comment: Anyone? Please help

Comment: You just have to keep reading. The non-rigid case is discussed after the rigid case.

Comment: Didn't you tell that the disc rotates about its centre? Here it says that it won't?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13178/discussion-between-kleingordon-and-awesome)